# How to use Eval() with a column name that contains a dot(.)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding

In my SQL Server table there is a column `slno.` (yes, it contains a dot) that is working fine in SQL Server. However, `<%#Eval("slno.")%>` is giving an error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'slno'.

How can this be solved? I can't change column name in database: I am getting data from `stored procedure` so I cannot modify it.

```
<ItemTemplate> <%#Eval("slno.") %> </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: just a guess. have you tried it enclosing in [] brackets?

Comment: There was an exact duplicate of this question about 5 minutes ago...

Comment: @SaQiB: Yes I tried it `Eval(["slno."])` and `Eval("[slno.]")` but none of them working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["slno."] %>
```

Alternatively use

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "slno.") %>
```

For MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

**EDIT - Another option:**

```
<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "slno.") %>
```

EDIT 2 - as per comments:

AFAIK `Eval` handles the string as an expression which it evaluates using some rules - these rules have special handling for the dot...

`GetPropertyValue` OTOH does not apply those rules (which means it is NOT a full replacement for `Eval` AFAIK) thus having the ability to handle cases where the dot handling of `Eval` leads to problems (like in this case).

Comment: then please show the exact declaration of the stored procedure which returns this column...

Comment: Now I am trying to use simple `select * from tbPRecord` but still getting error.

Comment: please see my EDIT above... and: if that does not work please show the exact declaration of the columns returned...

Comment: **NOW THAT IS A HIT** Pleas explain why `<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "slno.") %>` is working and others are not?

Comment: Because `Eval` handles the string as an expression which it evaluates using some rules (which have special handling for dot) while `GetPropertyValue` does not apply those rules (which means it is not a full replacement for `Eval` AFAIK)...

Comment: Thanks, DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "slno.") %> worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I Used DataBinder.GetPropertyValue() as it follows:

```
DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Name of my Fields with(Parentheses)")
```

and Worked like a Charm on a ASP.NET VB Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT AS in your SELECT SQL statement.

```
SELECT Tabl1.slno. AS slno_no_dot from Table1
```

than

```
<ItemTemplate> <%#Eval("slno_no_dot") %> </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue in a self-written customcontrol. In some cases I need to use the syntax "object.property" and sometimes I need to use "columnname.with.dots". Finally I solved it by using a Try-Catch block:

```
object value;
try
{
    // Try "Object.Property" approach...
    value = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, Fieldname);
}
catch
{    
    // fallback for columns containing dots or other special characters
    value = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(container.DataItem, Fieldname);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do not use `DataBinder.eval()`; `eval()` can not read field after dot(.).

Instead, use `DataBinder.GetPropertyValue()`