# Label text databind to a column alias with dot

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have this Select statement:

```
SELECT recordID As [Zap.st.] FROM SomeTable
```

When I try to bind the result to a GridView with template fields using an asp:Label I get this error:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Zap'
```

This is a sample GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMainData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zap.št." SortExpression="Zap.st." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblZapSt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Zap.st.") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried:

```
Text='<%# Eval("[Zap.st.]") %>'
Text='<%# Eval("'Zap.st.'") %>'
```

but none of these seem to work.

Edit: To further clarify my problem:

My Select statement is a View on Sql Server, the results in my asp.net come in as [Zap.st.], there is no reference that this is [recordID]

Comment: Hi, it's generally occurs due to misspelled column names, hence one should recheck that.

Comment: The problem is your aleas Name not the Eval function. If you use

`Text='<%# Eval("recordID") %>` it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question on SO, this is the solution:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblZapStD" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Zap.st.") %>' />
```

And this is the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574588/how-to-use-eval-with-a-column-name-that-contains-a-dot) with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMainData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zap.št." SortExpression="Zap.st." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblZapSt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("recordID") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: My Select statement is a View on Sql Server, the results in my asp.net come in as [Zap.st.], there is no reference that this is [recordID], I should say that in OP to clarify a bit more.

Comment: can u refer this link : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Exception---DataBinding-System.Data.DataRowView-does-not-contain-a-property-with-the-name-x.aspx