# bind DataItem with a space in the name

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm trying to bind dataitem in GridView like that:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Project No.") %>
```

and getting the error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Project No'.

the field is `Project No.` (with a dot `.`).
how can i bind that field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this : [] to indicatethat it is a column name.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.[Project No.]") %>
```

Comment: DataBinding: '[Project No' is not a valid indexed expression.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574588/how-to-use-eval-with-a-column-name-that-contains-a-dot

Answer (score 4):

```
 <%# Eval("Project No.") %>
```

note that your datatable/dataset should have Project No. exactly to work

**Update**

100% Working & Tested

```
   <%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem,"Project No.") %>
```

Comment: again: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Project No'. (not including '.')